# emptyList() vs emptySet(), is there any reason to chose one over the other if an instance of Collection is needed?

Tags: java, collections

In the *JDK*, there's `Collection.emtpyList()` and `Collection.emptySet()`. Both in their own right. But sometimes all that is needed is an empty, immutable instance of `Collection`. To me, there's no reason to chose one over the other as both implement all operations of `Collection` in an efficient way and with the same results. Yet each time I need such an empty collection I ponder which one to use for a second of two.

I do not expect to gain a deeper understanding of the *collections framework* from an answer to this question but maybe there's a subtle reason I could use to justify choosing one over the other without thinking about it ever again.

**An answer should state at least one reason preferring one of `Collection.emtpyList()` and `Collection.emptySet()` over the other in a context where they're functionally equivalent.** An answer is better if the stated reason is near the top of this list:

- There's a case where the type system is happier with one over the other (e.g. type inference allows shorter code with one than the other).
- There is a performance difference, maybe in some special case (e.g. if the empty collection is passed as an argument to some of the collection framework's static or instance methods like `Collections.sort()` or `Collection.removeAll()`).
- Choosing one over the other "makes more sense" in the general case, if you think about it.

#### Examples where this question arises

To give some context, here are two examples where I am in need of an empty, unmodifiable collection.

This is an example of an API that allows creating some object by optionally specifying a collection of objects that are used in the creation. The second method just calls the first one with an empty collection:

```
static void createObjectWithTheseThings(Collection<Thing> things) {
    ...
}

static void createObjectWithoutAnyThings() {
    createObjectWithTheseThings(Collections.emptyXXX());
}
```

This is an example of an Entity with state represented by an immutable collection stored in a non-final field. On initialization the field should be set to an empty collection:

```
class Example {
    // Initialized to an empty collection.
    private Collection<T> containedThings = Collections.emptyXXX();

    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess you wouldn't accept "`Collection.emptySet()` saves you one keystroke" as an answer?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Both methods return immutable versions of list / set. Where is it mentioned that only emptyList() returns an unmodifiable List and emptySet() doesn't?

Comment: I think we'll struggle to find any difference, but it may help if you describe the typical use cases when you need this? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve your underlying goal then to use these empty collections..

Comment: @Duncan -In the Source Code, comments provided for both the methods (empty#) are the same (and returned values are immutable for both).. I was just wondering why *a_horse_with_no_name* is mentioning the same only for emptyList().

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Your comment *is* ambiguous... :)

Comment: If you are casting the reference to a `Collection`, how could there ever be any difference *in the type system*? Are you asking "which should I cast to a `Collection`" or are you asking "do I get any benefit from my method taking a `List` or `Set` when it could just take a `Collection`"? I think those are very different questions, and it would be good to clarify.

Comment: @ammoQ If StackOverflow conclusively determines that there is no difference between the two, I think I'm going to base by decision on exactly that difference. :-)

Comment: @DanGetz I was tempted to annotate that statement in the question with an explanation that I can't imagine there being any difference for the type system. But I thought that maybe it would bring someone to an idea were it could make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have an answer that will make the top of your priority list but if I were you I'd settle on

```
Collections.emptySet
```

- Type inference was your first priority but I don't know if the choice can/should influence that given you were looking for an emptyCollection()
- On the second priority, think about any api that takes in a collection which performs differently (accidentally/intentionally) based on the sub-interfaces of the concrete object passed in. Aren't they more likely to offer varied performance based on the concrete implementations (as with an ArrayList or LinkedList) instead? The empty set/list are not modeled on any empty data structures anyway; they are dummy implementations - hence no real difference
- Based on java's modelling of these interfaces (which admittedly is not ideal), a Collection is very similar to a Set. In fact I think the methods are almost exactly the same. Logically too it looks OK with List being the specific-sub type that adds additional ordering concerns.

Now Collection and Set looking very similar(java-wise) brings up a question. If you are using a Collection type, it is clear it is not a list you want. Now the question is are you sure you don't mean a Set. If you don't, then are you using something like a **Bag** (surely there must be concrete instances which are not empty in the overall logic). So if you are concerned with say a **Bag**, then shouldn't it be up to the Bag api to provide an emptyBag() method?  Just wondering. btw, I'd stick with emptySet() in the meantime :)

Comment: I like your proposition that a _Set_ is more similar to a _Collection_ than a _List_. A _Bag_ would of course be even more similar but in my experience, collections that don't have an order generally also don't have duplicate elements.

Comment: Conceptual differences seem to be the only ones that can be put forth, so I'm going with this answer. And not only is `emptySet()` one character shorter than `emtpyList()`, because of symmetry it implies favoring `singleton()` over `singletonList()`, which saves 4 characters! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For the emptyXXX(), it really doesn't matter at all - since they are both *empty* (and they are unmodifieable, so they always stay empty) it doesn't matter at all. They will be equally suited to all operations Collection offers.

Take a look at what Collections really gives you there: Special implementations (the instances are shared across calls!). All relevant operations are dummy implementations that either return a constant result or immediately throw. Even iterator() is just a dummy with no state.

It wont make any notable difference at all.

Edit: You could say for the special case of emptyList/Set, they are semantically and complexity-wise the same at the Collecton interface level. All operations available on Collection are implemented by emptySet/List as O(1) operations. And since they're following both the contract defined by Collection, they are semantically identical too.

Comment: `EmptySet.add(E element)` is probably a few CPU cycles faster than `EmptyList.add(E element)`; not that it matters, since both throw an  `UnsupportedOperationException()`

Comment: @ammoQ How do you get to that conclusion?

Comment: @Feuermurmel He checked out the source code and saw that List.add(e) delegates to another signature to finally throw the exception while Set.add(e) directly throws.

Comment: @Durandal: Exactly. Sorry for not giving the explanation in my first comment; somehow it got lost somewhere between my mind and my keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The only situation I can imagine this making a difference is if the code that will use your `Collection` does something like this:

```
Collection<T> collection = ...
List<T> asAList;
if (collection instanceof List) {
    asAList = (List<T>) collection;
} else {
    asAList = new ArrayList<T>(collection);
}
```

Obviously in a case like this you would want to use `emptyList()`, while if the secret target type was a `Set`, you'd want `emptySet()`.

Otherwise, in terms of what "makes more sense", I agree with @ac3's logic that a generic `Collection` is like a Bag, and an empty immutable Set and empty immutable Bag are pretty much the same thing. However, a person very used to using immutable lists might find those easier to think of.